# How to add barcode to html file in android?

Tags: android, html, webview, barcode

My application print webview content from my custom html file.

When generate html file, how can I add barcode to that file?

I can create barcode by https://github.com/kenglxn/QRGen lib with object types (File,  ByteArrayOutputStream, Bitmap)
Example:

```
File file = QRCode.from("Hello World").file();
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = QRCode.from("Hello World").stream();
Bitmap myBitmap = QRCode.from("www.example.org").bitmap();
```

Which object type can I use to add barcode to html file and how?